# Increase font size in Firefox on iOS

Tags: ios, firefox

Is there a way to increase the font size for web pages rendered in Firefox for iOS?  I don’t mean in reading mode nor do I mean pinch-out zooming.

Is there a setting that I’m not seeing?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of either...  Safari does this (and does it well, easy setting at the bottom of the page), but Firefox doesn't seem to have an equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I‘ve the same problem. It seems that there is no way to increase fontsize in iOs-Firefox. Allegedly Firefox does this automatically.

But maybe the following helps you too:

In my special case I realized that my Settings (the three horizontal stripes – on the right side above) and here in the
eight line, were set on „original Desktop-Website View“ (I don‘t know the right English expression).
So I changed the View to „Mobile Website View“.
The result was an slightly increase of text size.